# How to use GROUP BY clause on a derived table in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I'm working on a complicated sql query and I always get oracle error ORA-00933 when executing it. I minimized the query to this minimal example:

```
SELECT foo.bar, sum(foo.baz) 
  FROM (SELECT  123  as bar,  5 as baz FROM dual) as foo
GROUP BY foo.bar
```

It seems to have to do with using the derived table and the GROUP BY clause.

How do I rewrite the query to support the GROUP BY clause on the derived table `foo`?

Comment: Why would you even need the group by here?

Comment: @Lucero Because I didn't want to bother you with the rest of the 10kB sql statement I'm working on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oracle does not support `as` for defining table aliases.

So try this:

```
SELECT foo.bar, sum(foo.baz) 
FROM (SELECT 123 as bar, 5 as baz FROM dual) foo
GROUP BY foo.bar;
```

Do use `as` (although it is optional) for column aliases.